# Custom dateFormat comparison in Spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I go about filtering by dates in Spark if the input data is in a different format.

My data is in `dd-MMM-yy` format
eg: `31-Jan-98`

This is what I am trying:

```
val filteredDate  = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(monthsToFilter).toString()
dataframe.filter(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(columnName),"dd-M-yy"))).gt(lit(filteredDate)))
```

The filtered data is empty even though there is data.

Comment: are you loading data from csv uaing the spark read api? did you mention the time format there?

Comment: no...not using time format there, i am reusing the csv read function in multiple locations, i dont want to specify format there. i have csv datasets which have multiple different formats

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution. Perhaps can become much cleaner. I would be glad to learn if this can be simplified

```
  override def filterByDate(dataframe: DataFrame,dateFormat: String, columnName: String, monthsToFilter: Int) ): DataFrame = {
    val filteredDate = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(monthsToFilter).toString()
    dataframe.filter(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(columnName), dateFormat))).gt(to_date(lit(filteredDate))))
  }
```